# Як правильно: в прямому етері, в прямому ефірі чи наживо?

Tags: вживання-слів, orthography, різниця-між-словами

На різних українських ТВ каналах можна почути різні варіанти - *в прямому етері*, *в прямому ефірі*, а також *наживо*.

В Вікіпедії [вказано](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%83_1999_%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83), що *в етері* з'явилось внаслідок проекту правопису 1999 року, який, на разі, не був прийнятий.

Проте деякі норми цього правопису використовують:

1. Видавництва Свічадо, Літопис, Критика.
2. Окремі його пункти наявні в
   мовленні телеканалу СТБ (у програмі новин).
3. Частина письменників
   (наприклад, Оксана Забужко) використовують цей правопис у своїх
   творах.
4. На офіційному сайті ВО «Свобода» значна частина новин
   написана з використанням елементів цього правопису.

*Наживо* (суб'єктивно) почали використовувати не так давно.

Який варіант є усталеним/нормативним?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Відповідно до Українського правопису 2015 року:

> "§ 88. F, Ph, Th
>   F і ph передаються літерою ф: фабрика, факт, фартух, фах, фаянс, федеративний, фейлетон, фігура, форма, фуга, футляр, офіційний, реформа; ефемерний, катастрофа, корифей, фараон, фізика, фізіологія, філософія, флегматик, фонетика, фосфор; Флоренція, Франція; Філіппіни, Фінікія; Лонгфелло, Фірдоусі, Фаон.
>
> Th залежно від того, як слово узвичаєне в українській мові, передається то літерою ф: арифметика, **ефір**, кафедра, логарифм, міф, орфографія, пафос, Федір, — то літерою т: бібліотека, ортодокс, ортопедія, театр, теорія; Тадей, Теодор."
>   [link](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil3.htm)

А "наживо" - синонім.

> нажи́во, присл.
>   //  У прямому ефірі.
>   Хто не встиг побачити і почути екс-держсекретаря наживо, побачили ввечері повтор, який демонстрували різні телеканали по кілька разів   (Дмитро Чобіт, Фарисеї.., 2006);
>   Він [інтернет-марафон] тривав понад шість годин і наживо транслювався на багатьох інтернет-ресурсах (Український тиждень, 2012, № 1).
>   [link](http://sum.in.ua/f/nazhyvo)

Comment: Я б додав інформацію про те, що "етер" було правильно ще до 1933 року, а не лише "внаслідок проекту правопису 1999 року"

Comment: @KyryloYatsenko так! Це ж та сама історія, мабуть, що й з г/х.
Було б цікаво зібрати десь в одному місці це все, всю цю плутанину зі звуками, і розібрати її на частини, розплутати віхоть.