# Як правильно: катедральний собор чи кафедральний собор?

Tags: граматика, spelling

Не раз стикався з різним варіантами наче одного і того ж слова. Як повинно бути правильно: *катедральний* собор чи *кафедральний* собор?

Чи можливо це різні за значенням слова і відповідно несуть різне смислове навантаження?

Приклад:

> Лати́нський **катедра́льний** собо́р [1](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80_(%D0%9B%D1%8C%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B2)) (в тексті статті)
>
> **Кафедральний** собор Святого Воскресіння [2](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80_%D0%A1%D0%B2%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%92%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F_(%D0%86%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%A4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA))

**UPDATE**

Питання немає прямої відповіді в запропонованому дублікаті. Кращим варіантом є звернутись до цього питання:

> [“Т” чи “ф” як відповідник “Th” (Θ) при запозиченні з
> грецької?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/438/%d0%a2-%d1%87%d0%b8-%d1%84-%d1%8f%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%96%d0%b4%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%96%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba-th-%ce%98-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%96-%d0%b7-%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%86%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%97)

Comment: @KyryloYatsenko, це питання не є прямим дублікатом питання http://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/380/260, хоча у відповідях прослідковуються відповіді і на це запитання.

Comment: Богдане, може переформулювати це запитання, щоб не тільки кафедральний/катедральний було в ньому піднято, а і ефір/етер, щоб у відповідях на Ваше запитання сконцентрувалася інформація про історію змін правописів в цих аспектах?

Comment: @myroslav http://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/438/Т-чи-ф-як-відповідник-th-Θ-при-запозиченні-з-грецької 
думаю, я впорався.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

На семантичному рівні - це абсолютні синоніми.

Слово походить з грецької мови і було запозичено українською паралельно через посередництво різних мов:

1) латини та польської (*катедра*);

2) російської (*кафедра*): згадаймо про нетиповість літери "ф" для української мови: його всіляко замінювали - наприклад, на Лівобережжі казали *Хведір* (це явище має назву субституція), а на Правобережжі - *Тодор* (грецький оригінал - *Θεόδωρος*).

Грецька літера **Θ** (тета/фіта) мала різні рефлекси в українській та російській мовах: [**т**] та [**ф**], а запозичення засвоювалися мовою непослідовно, тому й маємо "Афіни", але "атеней.

> Згідно з тезами харківського правопису, У словах грецького походження
>   клясичний правопис радить передавати літеру θ завжди через «т».
>   Наприклад, етер, катедра, міт, аритметика, логаритм, дитирамб,
>   ортографія, етіопський, Пітагор, Атени, Картагена, Корінт, Методій,
>   Теодор, Теодосій, Теофан тощо.

Етимологічний словник називає слово "катедра" застарілим, але 1985 рік видання чудово це пояснює. Але в такому разі застарілим має бути і слово "*патетичний*", бо ж "*пафос*".

Comment: На мою думку, все ж слід орієнтуватися на чинний затверджений правопис, якщо те чи інше правило ним регламентоване.

Comment: У тому й річ, що "залежно від того, як слово узвичаєне в мові" - не дуже  чітке пояснення, бо в різних регіонах воно могло по-різному узвичаїтися.

Comment: @Palacsinta http://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/438/Т-чи-ф-як-відповідник-th-Θ-при-запозиченні-з-грецької 
тут кажуть, що питання дублює інше питання, то ж я створив більш загальне.

Comment: @Palacsinta, ото ж, конкретно в цьому випадку на даний момент правильним варіантом є `кафедра`?

Comment: @Bohdan Kuts Згідно з чинним правописом, "Th залежно від того, як слово узвичаєне в українській мові, передається то літерою ф: арифметика, ефір, кафедра, логарифм, міф, орфографія, пафос, Федір, — то літерою т: бібліотека, ортодокс, ортопедія, театр, теорія; Тадей, Теодор", отже так.

Answer (score 5):

Відповідь така ж, як і на запитання "Як правильно: в прямому етері, в прямому ефірі чи наживо?"

Згідно з Українським правописом 2015 року: [link](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil3.htm)

> "§ 88. F, Ph, Th F і ph передаються літерою ф: фабрика, факт, фартух,
>   фах, фаянс, федеративний, фейлетон, фігура, форма, фуга, футляр,
>   офіційний, реформа; ефемерний, катастрофа, корифей, фараон, фізика,
>   фізіологія, філософія, флегматик, фонетика, фосфор; Флоренція,
>   Франція; Філіппіни, Фінікія; Лонгфелло, Фірдоусі, Фаон.
>
> Th залежно від того, як слово узвичаєне в українській мові,
>   передається то літерою ф: арифметика, ефір, **кафедра**, логарифм,
>   міф, орфографія, пафос, Федір, — то літерою т: бібліотека, ортодокс,
>   ортопедія, театр, теорія; Тадей, Теодор."