# "Т" чи "ф" як відповідник "Th" (Θ) при запозиченні з грецької?

Tags: запозичені-слова, spelling, transliteration, приголосні, from-greek

За чинним правописом маємо наступне правило:

> Th залежно від того, як слово узвичаєне в українській мові, передається то літерою `ф`: арифметика, ефір, кафедра, логарифм, міф, орфографія, пафос, Федір, — то літерою `т`: бібліотека, ортодокс, ортопедія, театр, теорія; Тадей, Теодор."

*...як слово узвичаєне в українській мові...* не є чітким поясненням того, як утворювати слова від грецької мови. Наприклад, ім'я *Федір* - це і є *Теодор*, тільки інакше транслітероване.

То ж питання наступне:

Як правильно передавати українською грецькі слова, що містять літеру `Θ` (тета/фіта)?

Comment: ор**т**одоксальна ор**ф**ографія — вона така ;-)

Comment: @bytebuster саме так! Просто вже назріло питання, не перший раз ставлять про щось конкретне: катедральний, кафедральний, ефір, етер. Я вирішив, що прийшов час для узагальненого питання.

Comment: Як правильно передавати в яких випадках? З одного боку, в пізніх грецизмах переважає передача Θ як Т (навіть у тих, що приходять у наш час через російську, пройшовши перед тим через західноєвропейські мови). З іншого боку, вам скажеш, що правильно передавати як Т, то всім Федорам і Федоренкам доведеться після цього міняти паспорти (бо це ім'я також прийшло з грецької). Тому, очевидно, порада стосується лише нових запозичень (зроблених після цієї поради), у решті випадків — за традицією. У сучасній грецькій θ звучить як [θ] — тобто, як th в англ. think (тинк, финк, синк — як краще передати?).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

За чинним, а саме 2019 року, правописом вже так:

> [**§ 123. Буквосполучення *th* у словах грецького походження**](https://mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/zagalna%20serednya/05062019-onovl-pravo.pdf#page=125)
>
> Буквосполучення **th** у словах грецького походження передаємо звичайно буквою **т**: *антоло́гія, антрополо́гія, апте́ка, а́стма, бібліоте́ка, католи́цький, теа́тр, тео́рія, ортодо́кс, ортопе́дія, Амальте́я, Промете́й, Те́кля, Таї́сія, Теодо́р.* У словах, узвичаєних в українській мові з **ф**,
> допускається орфографічна варіантність на зразок: *ана́фема* і *ана́тема*, *дифіра́мб* і *дитира́мб*, *ефі́р* і *ете́р*, *ка́федра* і *кате́дра*, *логари́фм* і *логари́тм*, *міф*, *міфоло́гія* і *міт*, *мітоло́гія*, *Агата́нгел* і *Агафа́нгел*, *Афі́ни* і *Ате́ни*, *Борисфе́н* і *Бористе́н*, *Демосфе́н* і *Демосте́н*, *Ма́рфа* і *Ма́рта*, *Фесса́лія* і *Тесса́лія* та ін.

Тобто всюди **т**, подеколи можна і **ф** як парабіжну форму.

Answer (score 19):

[Клясичний український правопис](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81) - радикальний, але послідовний правопис:

> у словах грецького походження клясичний правопис радить передавати
>   літеру θ завжди через «т». Наприклад, етер, катедра, міт, аритметика,
>   логаритм, дитирамб, ортографія, етіопський, Пітагор, Атени, Картагена,
>   Корінт, Методій, Теодор, Теодосій, Теофан тощо.

[Неклясичний український правопис](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil3.htm#par88) більш лояльний, але від того не більш зрозумілий:

> Th залежно від того, як слово узвичаєне в українській мові,
>   передається то літерою ф: арифметика, ефір, кафедра, логарифм, міф,
>   орфографія, пафос, Федір, — то літерою т: бібліотека, ортодокс,
>   ортопедія, театр, теорія; Тадей, Теодор.

Оскільки не міг радянський уряд довго терпіти клясичні західноукраїнські витребеньки, то правописом 1946 року постановили писати [**ф**] у словах, запозичених через старослов'янську, а  [**т**] - у словах, засвоєних українською мовою за посередництва латини (романських мов). Здається, відтоді нічого не змінилося, тож маємо те, що маємо.

Comment: "Картаґена нашої провінційности мусить бути зруйнована" Ю. Шевельов, «Над озером. Баварія»

Answer (score 7):

**Ознайомтеся зі [збіркою думок](//r2u.org.ua/node/54)**

---

##### [Борис Грінченко](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D1%80%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE_%D0%91%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81_%D0%94%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87) • Словарь української мови

«Въ виду того, что звукъ *ф* у большинства украинскаго народа выговаривается какъ *хв* (передъ гласной, кромѣ *у*) или *х* (передъ согласной и передъ *y*), мы, составляя словарь на букву *ф*, помѣстили въ него лишь тѣ слова, для которыхъ въ нашихъ матеріалахъ не нашлось дубликата съ *хв* или *х* [При этомъ принята была во вниманіе оговорка Номиса въ предисловіи къ его сборнику пословицъ. что онъ *ф* вездѣ, гдѣ оно у него встрѣчалось, замѣнялъ звуками *хв*]; всѣ же слова, которыя встрѣчены только съ *хв* и *х* или, рядомъ съ этими звуками, также и съ *ф*, помѣщены нами на букву *х*, примѣры-же къ нимъ, конечно, были оставлены съ тѣмъ изъ этихъ звуковъ, съ какимъ были встрѣчены. Если какое либо слово съ звуками *хв*, *х* имѣло одно значеніе, а съ зв. *ф* – другое, тогда оно, съ соотвѣтствующими значеніями, помѣщалось и на *ф* и на *х* со взаимными ссылками одного на другое. Незначительныя и немногія отступленія отъ этихъ правилъ обусловлены желаніемъ предоставить болѣе удобствъ въ пользованіи словаремъ и понятны безъ объясненій.»

Тому, власне, нема у Грінченка Афанасія, Феодосія, Федора але є Тодос(ь), Хведось, Ахтанасій, Охтанас, Опанас, Хведір, Тодір. І є «катедра», та приклад з І. Левицького: «Наука по катедрах кульгала або дрімала».

##### [Андрій Залізняк](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%BA_%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B9_%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B9%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87)  • Древненовгородский диалект

«Буквы ф и θ. Для передачи фонемы /ф/ (встречавшейся только в заимствованных словах), в берестяных грамотах в разные периоды используются разные буквы. В самый ранний период отмечено ф – в № 591 (азбука), XI) и 605 (1 треть XII); тоже в несколько более поздних грамотах № 675 и 234 (сер. XII). Первые примеры θ – в № 559 и 560 (сер. XII): возможно к этому времени относится № 381. Со 2 половины XII по конец XIII в. господствует θ (около 40 грамот): ф встретилось в эту эпоху только в № 717, 729, 152 (не считая Смол. 10). Сначала XIV в. буква ф начинает заметно распространяться. Со 2 половины XIV в. буква ф уже господствует: она встречается  примерно в 6 раз чаще, чем θ».

##### [Володимир Калашник](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80_%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87)

«Пропоноване проектом паралельне вживання іншомовних слів з приголосними ф і т може стосуватися лише «вільних» стилів (художнього та публіцистичного), в інших (науковому та офіційно-діловому) необхідно зберегти більш поширені написання: кафедра, а не катедра; міфологія, а не мітологія; орфографія, а не ортографія (пор. ортопедія), хоч наша мова й не послідовна у таких випадках відтворення слова-першооснови».

*Випис найуживаніших слів (пропуски – інші відповідники в мові)*

| Мова | ἀνάθεμα | ἀριθμητική | αἰθήρ | καθέδρα | μυθικός | Ἀθήνα |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Англ. | Anáthema | arithmetic | ether | cathedra | myth | Athens |
| Еспан. | Anatema | aritmética | éter | cátedra | mito | Atenas |
| Італ. | Anatèma | aritmètica | ètere | càttedra | mito | Atène |
| Нім. |  | Aritmetik | Äther | Katheder | Mythos | Athen |
| Франц. | anathème | aritmétique | éther |  | mythe | Athènes |
| Фін. | anateema | aritmetiikka | eetteri | katederi | myytti | Ateena |
| Румун. | anátemă | aritmétică | etér | catédră | mit | Aténa |
| Угор. |  | aritmetika | éther |  | mithosz | Athén |
| Словац. |  | aritmetika | éter | katedra | mýtus | Atény |
| Чес. |  | aritmetika | éter | katedra | mýtus | Atény, Athény |
| Серб. | анатема | аритметика | етер, етар | катедра | мит | Антина |
| Болгар. | анатема | аритметика | éтер | катéдра | мит | (атинянин) |
| Польс. | anatema | arytmetyka | eter | katedra | mit | Ateny |
| Білорус. | анафема | арыфметыка | эфір | кафедра | міф | Афіны |
| Рос. | анафема | арифметика | эфир | кафедра | миф | Афины |
| Укр.<sup>1</sup> | анафема | арифметика | ефір | кафедра | міф | Афіни |
| Укр.<sup>2</sup> | анахтема | арихметика |  | катедра |  | афини (рослина) |
| Укр.<sup>3</sup> | анатема | аритметика | етер | катедра | міт | Атени |

> 1. *Підписано як «чинний», тобто якийсь до 2019 року*
> 2. Словник Грінченка, 1909
> 3. Словник Голоскевича, 1930

Як бачимо виняток становлять тільки 3 мови: білоруська, російська, українська. До того ж білоруська і українська в 20-х роках XX ст. прийшла до послідовного передавання «θ» як «т», а потім почалась епоха «спільної термінології».

Ще є декілька слів, стосовно яких в українській робили напіввиняток, зокрема грец. Ἄθως (чес. Athos, словац. Athos, серб. Атос), а рос. Афон в словнику Голоскевича подано як Áтос (частіше Афон).

*[Перелік власних назв]*

Недарма автор українського перекладу «Iліяди» й «Одіссеї» Микола Хомичевський, за висловом Миколи Бажана, «видатний майстер нашої української літератури, творець такого перекладу «Іліади», якому може позаздрити будь-яка література...», обрав псевдонім Борис Тен (від Бористена).

##### [Ольга Кочерга](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0_%D0%9E%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B3%D0%B0_%D0%94%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0)

«Проєкт частково усуває непослідовність у написанні термінів грецького походження з латинською буквосполукою th, що відповідає грецькій літері θ (за якою логікою, наприклад, маємо згідно з чинною редакцією по-різному писати слова, що походять від того самого грецького «ритмос» (число) – ритм та арифметика, алгоритм та логарифм тощо). Проєкт дозволяє написання таких слів і через ф, і через т, і можна з певністю сказати, що за короткий час написання через т домінуватиме. Про це свідчить хоча б той факт, що українські відповідники чужомовних природничих термінів із префіксом ortho- однозначно, всі без винятку, мають префікс орто- (ортокисень, ортогональний, ортоскопічний, ортовісь, ортогексагональний, ортодромія, ортокислота, ортоповерхня, ортосиметричний тощо; в математиці є навіть термін ортографічна проєкція). Зазначу побіжно, що журналісти торік приділили невиправдано велику увагу зміні написання вживаної у ЗМІ метафори ефір – етер, тоді як хеміки вже давно без зайвого галасу унормували назви етер та естер, прийняті у довоєнні часи, замість складного та простого ефірів, накинутих через ненаукове втручання у наукову термінологію (це окреме питання, не торкатимусь його тут, хоча воно дуже тісно пов’язане із джерелами багатьох правописних негараздів).»

##### [Василь Німчук](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D1%96%D0%BC%D1%87%D1%83%D0%BA_%D0%92%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C_%D0%92%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87) • [Проблеми українського правопису в 20 столітті](http://r2u.org.ua/node/126) • [Сучасні проблеми українського правопису](http://r2u.org.ua/node/123)

*[Історія і всяке инше]*

Беручи до уваги історичну і сучасну орфографічну практику та перспективи контактів із західноєвропейськими мовами, варто, на нашу думку, узаконити паралельне вживання відповідних слів із **ф** і **т**: *логарифм – логаритм, міф – міт, Гефсиманія – Гетсиманія* і т. д. Ідеться, звичайно, про назви, які походять із грецької мови або запозичені через її посередництво і мають у звуковому складі **θ** (а не про заміну всякого іншомовного **ф** на **т**, зокрема в антропонімах Фрідріх, Фауст, Фаберже.»

##### [Іван Огієнко](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%86%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%96%D0%BE%D0%BD_(%D0%9E%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%94%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE))

##### [Олексій Павловський](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%9E%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%96%D0%B9_%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87)

ф треба вимовляти як хв: фарба – хварба, филя – хвиля, фукга – хвукга, форый – хворий.

##### [Олександр Пономарів](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B2_%D0%9E%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80_%D0%94%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87)

##### [Іван Вихованець](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%86%D1%8C_%D0%86%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD_%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87) (згодний)

Почну зі слів етер, катедра, міт тощо, які пропонуємо вживати поряд з їхніми фонетичними варіантами ефір, кафедра, міф та ін. У грецькій мові в цих словах немає звука ф; давні греки вимовляли там придиховий т, сучасні – міжзубний т. У переважній більшості старих і нових запозичень із грецької та інших мов ми також передаємо його через т: акант, бібліотека, етика, лабіринт, математика, тема, хризантема тощо. Але є невелика кількість слів, де замість т вживаємо ф: міф, пафос (пор. однокореневі патетика, патогенний), орфоепія (пор. ортодоксія, ортогональний). Тож ми й пропонуємо писати міт, катедра тощо. Але щоб не було дуже різкої зміни, варіанти міф, кафедра тощо теж нехай залишаються нормативними».

---

*[З «Фонеми г та ґ»]*

«Звук **ф** слов'янські мови запозичили; українська мова (разом із білоруською) чинила йому опір найдовше: Сте**п**ан, карто**п**ля, **кв**асоля, **П**илип, **П**илипівка й ін. Тепер його маємо й ми, і, певна річ, немає ні сенсу, ні потреби викидати його зі слів **феномен**, **філантропія**, **філософія**, **футуризм** та численних інших. А ось уживати його там, де він відсутній у мові-джерелі, справа вельми сумнівна. Ідеться про грецький міжзубний звук, що позначається літерою (лат. th). Майже в усіх мовах він відтворюється літерою т (крім російської). Ми теж здебільшого на його місці вживаємо т. Але в небагатьох словах ніяк не можемо відійти від стереотипів, нав'язаних нам із північного сходу. Думається, настав час відновити звукову справедливість і поряд зі словами бібліотека, гіяцинт, Еритрея, лабіринт, Лета, метод, ортогональний, ортодоксальний, театр, тема, теорія та багатьма-багатьма іншими писати й вимовляти *[…]*

##### М. Протасов • Об упорядочении и унификации античной транскрипции (1940)

«Немалые затруднения возникают при передаче греческой «теты» (θ). Транскрибирование ее через «ф» имело некоторый смысл при существовании в русском алфавите специальной буквы θ (фиты), с уничтожением же ее передача «теты» буквой «ф» нелепа и идет вразрез с западной традицией. Поэтому, допуская наличие «ф» в ряде традиционных имен (Клисфен, Агафокл и т. п.), в большинстве случаев все-таки рекомендуется передавать «тету» через «т»: Теопомп (Θεόπομπος), Теофраст (Θεόφραστος), тесмотеты (θεσμοτέται)».

##### [Юрій Шевельов](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%AE%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B9_%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87)

*[З «Історична фонологія української мови»]*

«…звук f, як і g, потрапив в українську лише разом із запозиченими словами. При цьому одначе, між ними були дві суттєві розбіжності: по-перше, він був упроваджений набагато раніше внаслідок контактування з греками, тобто на самому початку існування української окремішності в рамцях праслов’янського контимууму: по-друге, він був підпертий авторитетом Церкви. Відповідно, його поширення мало йти щаблями суспільної гієрархії не знизу вгору, а згори вниз. У правописі його ніколи не намагалися уникати: навпаки траплялися надпоправні написання з ф на недоречних місцях. Незважаючи на все це (або саме через це), звук f залишився чужим і зовсім не защепився в говірній мові… Тому історія f в українській мові, то є по сутті не його власна історія, а радше хроніка послідовних переходів від одного його замінника до другого, адже впродовж приблизно тисячолітніх марних намагань прищепити звук f ці замінники таки мінялися, найдавнішим із них був, вочевидь, приголосний p… Приблизно тим часом датуються варіанти заміни f на v, хоча застосовувано їх далеко рідше… Найдавніші приклади заміни f на p та v не конче мусять бути українські з походження. Вони могли десь початково постати десь поміж балканських слов’ян… Однак українські par excellence способи заміни f пов’язані з застосуванням x, а трохи згодом – над усе xv (у ґрунті речі, африкати типу x<sup>w</sup>)… Щоправда існує – вочевидь віднедавно – група говірок, де і звукосполука xv (ще праслов’янська), і звук x<sup>w</sup> перетворилися на f, цього разу власного виробництва, – вперше за всю історію української мови.»

---

*[З «Так нас навчали правильних проізношеній»]*

«Приклад, до якого тепер переходжу, сучасному українському інтеліґентові, напевне, здасться особливо драстичним, тут бо оцінка мовних вартостей відповідно до чужої мови закоренилася особливо глибоко. Мова йтиме про звук, що вживається виключно в чужих словах, ***ф***. Цей приголосний виступав у багатьох позиках з чужих мов, насамперед західноевропейських, але в старших запозиченнях мова заступала його на ***п*** (напр., *Пилип, Остап, пляшка*) або на ***х*** (напр., *Хома, хура*), аж поки, від XV ст., не розвинулася африката ***хв***, дуже характеристична саме для української мови й дуже в ній поширена, але за малими винятками (*хвиля, хвіртка*...), не допущена до літературної мови. Низька соціяльна оцінка двозвука ***хв*** освіченими колами спершу постала в контактах з мовами польською, німецькою й латиною, але в новітні часи її посилили і остаточно ствердили контакти з російською мовою (в якій звук ***ф*** "природний" тому, що там він розвинувся і у власних словах у процесі нормального фонетичного розвитку й набув фонемного статусу).»

##### [Іван Ющук](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AE%D1%89%D1%83%D0%BA_%D0%86%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD_%D0%9F%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87)

«Нічого страшного не станеться, коли одні писатимуть міф, ефір, сад Гефсиманський, а інші - міт, етер, сад Гетсиманський, як ми й тепер вживаємо то Тадей, Тодось, Марта; то Фадей, Феодосій, Марфа.»