# Про переклад "Колгоспу тварин" Джорджа Орвелла видавництвом "Прометей" (1945 рік)

Tags: переклад, значення-слів

У творі "Колгосп тварин" Джорджа Орвелла у перекладі Івана Чернятинського (видавництво "Прометей") [зустрів](http://litopys.org.ua/novela/kolghosp.htm) велику кількість незвичних слів та написань, зокрема:

> З **анґлійської** мови переклав ІВАН ЧЕРНЯТИНСЬКИЙ
>
> **Ґ. ОРУЕЛ** ВИДАВНИЦТВО «ПРОМЕТЕЙ»
>
> Наголовок оригіналу: George Orwell, Animal Farm, 1945
>
> Авторизований переклад з анґлійської мови. Права українського
>   перекладу застережені за видавництвом.  Окладинка: М. Григоріїв.

В передмові видавництва цікавим є такий фрагмент:

> Це ціла когорта **інтеллєктуалістів** різних національностей. Між ними
>   письменники, політики, революціонери. Це ті «бунтарі» проти
>   **совєтського «міту»**, для яких точкою вихідною є не капітуляція чи культ
>   **назадництва**, але боротьба за поступ. Між ними багато прихильників
>   нашої справи. Якщо йде про **Оруела**, то читач зможе сам ствердити з
>   передмови його ідейну спорідненість з наймолодшим прогресивним
>   українством.

Питання, що виникли під час читання:

1. Вперше зустрічаю напис ан**ґ**лійської, що це за правопис чи правило?
2. Що означає `совєтського «міту»` (міфу?) і чому `совєтського` (радянського?).
3. Що означає `назадництво` і чи є воно нормативним в сучасній українській мові?  ("У своїх маніфестах «авангардівці» виступали проти «назадництва» й відсталості, але в творчій практиці були еклектиками" - [джерело](http://esu.com.ua/search_articles.php?id=42264), і тут `назадництво` стоїть в лапках).
4. Чому `Оруел` (в [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B6%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B6_%D0%9E%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BB) вживаються варіанти `Орвелл` та `Орвел`) і `Ґ.` (невже `Ґеорґ`)?
5. Чи є стиль перекладу унікальним для конкретно видавництва Прометей (враховуючи історичний контекст) чи подібний стиль зустрічається ще десь?

<sup>Можливо, деякі питання є сенс виділити як окремі питання, але, оскільки я не знаю, чи є прямий зв'язок між ними, то поки задаю їх всі разом.</sup>

Comment: Щодо Ґеорґ, то це варіант транслітерації цього імені українською. Але взагалі для української мови більш характерним є саме транскрибування іншомовних імен, тобто мало би бути Джьордж

Comment: Думаю що на більшу частину питань можна відповісти виходячи з того що видавництво "Прометей" працювало у Мюнхені, а звідси використання (швидше за все) Харківського правопису (Вікіпедія каже що саме його використовує діаспора https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81).

Comment: Щодо "міту" див. http://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/438/36

Comment: про совєтський тут висвітлюється, наприклад https://day.kyiv.ua/uk/blog/suspilstvo/radyanskiy-chi-sovietskiy-yake-slovo-vzhivati @Artemix якщо точніше, то видавництво працювало в Новому Ульмі, а не в Мюнхені;

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ви ж розумієте, що в 1945 році Орвелл не міг бути виданим ні у видавництві «Політвидав України», ні у видавництві «Наукова думка», тому логічно, що правописні норми, до яких ми звикли в УРСР "трохи" відрізнялися від тих, якими послуговувалися наші земляки у еміграції.

Перекладач  “Колгоспу тварин” Ігор Чернятинський (Шевченко Ігор Іванович) народився у еміграції (був сином члена уряду УНР), навчався в Українському вільному університеті у Мюнхені, працював викладачем Каліфорнійського, Мічиганського, Колумбійського і Гарвардського університетів.

Отже логічно, що мова книжки "трішечки" відрізнялася від тієї до якої ми звикли, також у видавництві "Прометей" не було редакторів, завдання яких полягало у втіленні програми по "[сближению русского и украинских языков](https://parafia.org.ua/biblioteka/statti/1930-ti-roky-ukrajinska-mova-v-dobu-velykoho-teroru/)"...

Цей стиль не є унікальним для "Прометея", цей стиль спільний для всієї емігрантської літератури, а до 1933 року так писали і в Україні. Якщо цікаво, раджу прочитати книгу "[Мовна норма: знищення, пошук, віднова](http://shron.chtyvo.org.ua/Farion_Iryna/Movna_norma_znyschennia_poshuk_vidnovlennia_kultura_movlennia_publichnykh_liudei.djvu)"

**Міт**.

Грецькі слова з літерою `θ` свого часу було засвоєні українцями через літ. "`т`" (аритмія, ортопед, міт), це підтверджують словники:

Російсько-український академічний словник 1924–33рр. (А. Кримський, С. Єфремов)

> Миф –
>   1) міт (-ту). [Міт про рай (Л. Укр.)];
>
> 2) (перен.: сказка, вымысел) ка́зка, ба́йка, ви́гадка, небили́ця.

Російсько-український словник 1930р. (О. Ізюмов)

> Миф – міт (род. мі́ту).

Чому "*совєтський*"? Можливо деяка зневага перекладача та бажання підкреслити, що та ідеологія як і її назва була чужою українському народу.

**Назадництво** — ретроградство, реакційність.

Answer (score 1):

Треба мати на увазі, що мова діяспорян (як і мова материкової України) не могла не зазнавати впливу мов правлячих націй тих держав, де мешкали українці. Якщо в англійській слово Soviet запозичили неадаптованим, то й тамтешні українці слідували цій моді (попри неможливість сполучення «вє» в чистій українській мові, де, як ми знаємо, м'яких губних приголосних не існує).

Щодо міт/міф, Фіви/Теби і т.д. — йдеться про два різні шляхи запозичення грецьких слів в українську мову. θ=ѳ=ф, або ж θ=th=т — в залежності від того, пройшло слово через церковнослов'янську й російську мову, чи через латинську й польську. Західна традиція орієнтується на давньогрецьку вимову, східна — на новогрецьку з подальшою східнослов'янською корекцією (через що, зокрема, ми кажемо Федір, а не Тедір). Очевидно, для «Великої України» типовим шляхом запозичення нових слів у ХІХ-ХХст. був російський шлях, тоді як Галичина так само природньо приймала їх через польську, тому склалося дві паралельні норми. Спроба їх узгодити була у Харківському правописі 1927р., але його незабаром скасували, тож пропонована ним передача θ як т так і не встигла прижитись.

Лєкання/лькання («інтеллєктуалістів») в запозиченнях не підтримувалося, здається, навіть і скрипниківкою — це артефакти інших правописів, що продовжували функціонувати на західноукраїнських землях і в діаспорі.

Comment: _м'яких губних приголосних не існує_. Що гадаєте щодо сучасного слова [як приклад] _[свято](http://sum.in.ua/s/svjato)_? Також наразї вживають _совєцький_ як режим з вельми негативною окрасою (тотожнього до нацизму).

Comment: Свято в желехівці записувалось як сьвято, що більш відповідає його точній вимові: м'якість переходить на попередню зубну приголосну, «я» звучить радше як дифтонгоїд (у вимові частини носіїв — практично «сьвйато»), саме ж «в» лише ледь пом'якшується. Також, якщо Ви намагаєтесь писати желехівкою, то могли звернути увагу, що після «в» (та решти губних) вживається непом'якшуюче «і», тоді як  пом'якшуюче «ї» — ніколи. Щодо політичного забарвлення: введення в українську мову чужої фонетики може виражати також і повагу — в УРСР 60-х років «Ленін» вимовляли як «Лєнін», з поваги до вождя.