# Переклад назви географічного обʼєкта

Tags: переклад, from-russian, власні-назви, запозичені-слова, from-greek

Є книга російського автора з описом географічних об'єктів небесного тіла. Згадуючи один з таких об'єктів, автор використовує назву, прийняту в російськомовній науковій літературі, зазначаючи, що в англомовній вживається інша. В українській вікі бачимо транскрибовану англомовну назву.

Яку з назв краще використати при перекладі текста українською?

Оновлення.

Йдеться про плато на Марсі: в тексті - "Фарсида", в англомовній літературі - "Tharsis", в українській вікі - "[Тарсис](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81)".

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/438/ Я схиляюся до того, щоб закрити це запитання як дублікат, але можливо, автор уточнить/доповнить запитання, якщо йдеться не про транслітерацію «Θ» у запозиченнях із грецької.

Comment: @bytebuster але тут йдеться про латину

Comment: @Yola, точніше, — про [арамейське слово](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarshish), яке до словʼянських мов потрапило, як і більшість своїх сучасників, через грецьку. Як Феодор/Теодор.

Comment: @bytebuster ваш коментар схожий на відповідь:)

Comment: додаючи до своєї відповіді: дуже сподіваюся, що українською перекладаєте напряму, не користуючись російськими відповідниками.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Як вже зазначено в коментарі, частина відповіді на ваше запитання знаходиться тут:

["Т" чи "ф" як відповідник "Th" (Θ) при запозиченні з грецької?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/438/240)

В наступному коментарі бачимо слово [תרשיש](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%AA%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%A9_(%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%A8)) - яке на івриті читається як "Таршиш". Перехід від звуку "ш" до звуку "с" зрозумілий, бо в арамейських мовах ці звуки позначаються однаковою літерою і розрізняються тільки розташуванням крапки над цією літерою (в івриті) або  наявністю/відсутністю трьох крапок над цією літерою (в арабській). Таким чином, слова з літерою "шин" з арамейських мов часто потрапляють до романських, германських і слов’янських вже з літерою "сін".

Давайте пройдемося іншими слов’янськими мовами, щоби не зациклюватися на російській:

1. [Болгарська](https://bg.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81_(%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81)) - Тарсис
2. [Чеська](https://cs.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tharsis) - Tharsis
3. [Польська](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tharsis) - Tharsis
4. [Хорватська](https://hr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tharsis) - Tharsis
5. [Словацька](https://sk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tharsis) - Tharsis
6. [Словенська](https://translate.google.com/#sk/sl/Tharsis) - Tharsis
7. [Білоруська](https://be.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%86%D1%8B%D1%8F_%D0%A4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%B0) - Фарсіда

Маємо: щонайменше 6 слов’янських мов із транслітерацією "Тарсіс/Tharsis", і дві слов’янські мови (російська й білоруська (друга ще й під впливом першої, тобто, не можемо казати про самостійне рішення саме так транслітерувати)) з - "Фарсіда/Фарсида".

Не знаходжу, як змінювалося це слово в російській. Роблю припущення, що їм воно як завжди просто "так лучше звучит".

Не бачу жодної причини брати до уваги транслітераційну практику північно-східного сусіда при перекладі книг на українську — в цій практиці бракує мінімальної логіки.

Сміло використовуйте міжнародну транслітерацію. Українцям, які читають переклади з назвою, що співзвучна назвам того місця в інших мовах, буде легше пізнавати світ, бо вони знатимуть, про що йдеться, а не здогадуватимуться, що "Тарсіс", або "|Th|aрсіс" - то, насправді, "наша" "Фарсіда".