# Чому Роберт Бош, а Ієронімус - Босх?

Tags: власні-назви, фонетика, іноземні-імена, іншомовні-слова

Ходила на фільм "Дивовижний світ Ієроніма Босха". 
Фільм англійською мовою з українськими субтитрами.

Звернула увагу на те, що англійською прізвище митця пишеться Bosch і вимовляється [bɒʃ], так само, як і прізвище [Роберта Боша](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Bosch), засновника німецької електротехнічної та машинобудівної фірми [Robert Bosch GmbH](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Bosch_GmbH).

Спочатку подумала, що така різниця у вимові українською від того, що живописець - нідерландець, і орієнтуються на оригінальну вимову. Але ж ні, стаття у [англійській Вікіпедії](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hieronymus_Bosch) пише (і озвучує), що транскрипція прізвища голландською [bɔs].

**Чому ж тоді українською Босх? Звідки й чому з'явився [h]?**

Answer (score 6):

Я не знаю, на чому це ґрунтується, але [інструкції з передачі українською мовою географічних назв і термінів від ДНВП «Картографія»](//web.archive.org/web/20170816063935/http://ukrmap.com.ua/services/kodeksi-ustalenoji-praktiki/) відрізняються:

- у нідерландських назвах:

  - *s* передається як *с* у всіх позиціях,
  - *ch* передається як *х*, але наприкінці слова не передається;

  <sub>(приклади: *Baarschot* — *Барсхот*; *Heesch* — *Гес*; *Brielsche Maas* — *Брілсе-Маас*)</sub>
- у німецьких назвах *sch* завжди передається як *ш*.

Це, звісно, не стосується людських імен. Навіть щодо географічних назв настанови Укркартографії не завжди виконуються (приклад: Бразилія, що за нормами Укркартографії має називатися *Браз**і**лією*). Навіть при застосуванні правил Укркартографії до нідерландського імені *Bosch* воно мало б транслітеруватися як *Бос*, а не *Босх*.

Але просто що я хотів проілюструвати цим? Що традиції передачі назв з різних мов справді відрізняються. І принаймні в частині випадків нідерландстке *sch* передається як *сх*.

Далі це все помножується на історичну заплутаність (можливо, раніше в нідерландській мові *sch* читалося як *сх* навіть у кінці слова; принаймні хоча б у деяких діалектах; або можливо, колишні редактори (XV ст.?) просто *вважали*, що воно читається як *сх*, через слабкі знання нідерландської, і відтоді помилково зафіксувалося так). І, звісно, [P. Vovk певною мірою правий](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/2608), що це також домножується на наслідування інших мов (у російській випадково зафіксували неправильно — або не неправильно, а колись чи у якомусь діалекті справді була вимова *сх*, але, незважаючи на зміну нідерландської вимови чи ролі нідерландських діалектів, російська вимова залишилася — і ми в результаті теж маємо *сх*).

Але я незгоден з P. Vovk у тому, що сусіди абсолютно не мають правил і запозичують зовсім як заманеться. Те, як проходять запозичення у певній мові (наприклад, *Гітлер*, але *Хеніке*) завжди є наслідком певних процесів у мові-оригіналі або мові-акцепторі. Але от чи варто в ідеалі аслідувати ці процеси з чужої мови — інше вже окреме питання.

Comment: у всіх своїх відповідях на цю тему я наголошую лише на одному: спочатку українську мову треба від’єднати від російської в цьому плані, а потім питати "чому так?". Бо зараз відповідь така: ми зробили так, як росіяни, а вони зробили так, тому що... Але стоп, яка різниця, чому вони так зробили, ми що, не можемо запозичити від мови ориґіналу? У будь-якому разі заапвоутив і вас. Я відразу сказав, що злий з цього приводу.

Comment: @P.Vovk, ну, **іноді** те, як вони зробили, має сенс. Але в цілому **згоден**. По-моєму: варто дивитися і розглядати їхній спосіб як один із варіантів (на рівні з іншими), але не тупо наслідувати, не думаючи.

Answer (score 4):

Насправді, відповідь тут, перші дві - точно: [Правила вживання букв г/х при перекладі іншомовних термінів (гакер, гостинг)](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/347/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2-%D0%B3-%D1%85-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%96-%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85-%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B2-%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3)

Також тут: [Переклад назви географічного об`єкта](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/1367/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B8-%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%96%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%94%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0/1370#1370)

Бо Україна, Білорусь і Росія мають схожі проблеми у таких випадках і складно відходять від загальнопринятих на цих теренах звичаях транслітерації і вимови запозичених власних імен.

Так само, як Левіафан вживається з літерою "ф" тільки у трьох цих мовах, так і Босх пишеться і читається через "ес-ха" тільки у трьох цих мовах.

Це відповідь на всі наші запитання з приводу запозичення і транслітерації.

Досліджується це все дуже просто, на вікіпедії транслітерація будь-якого такого запозиченого слова перевіряється на відповідність західним і південним слов’янським мовам (коли вже не ориґіналу), а потім - східним і північним.

Так і з Бошем:

Польською - Боc. https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hieronim_Bosch

Чеською - Бош. https://cs.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hieronymus_Bosch

Словакською - Бос. https://sk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hieronymus_Bosch

Словенською - Бош. https://sl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hieronymus_Bosch

Хорватською - Бос. https://hr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hieronymus_Bosch

Болґарською - Бош. https://bg.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%99%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%81_%D0%91%D0%BE%D1%88

Сербською - Бош. https://sr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B8%D1%98%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC_%D0%91%D0%BE%D1%88

Росія, Україна, Білорусь - Босх.

Власник компанії "Бош" нашою мовою з тої самої причини. Бо ми лінґвістично від когось залежні, а ті, від кого ми залежні, не дуже дружать з лінґвістичною лоґікою транслітерації, тому у цьому разі хтось транслітерував правильно, а з художником не пощастило.

Не бачу сенсу шукати ґрунтовніші, засадничніші причини таких речей.

Треба просто вбити залежність від сусідів, які не мають конкретних правил, а запозичують так, як їм заманеться.

Comment: @P.Vovk, у мовах на основі латинки вимова запозичених слів не завжди підкоряється звичним правилам читання (це — недолік прямого запозичення, без транслітерації). Наприклад, за німецькими правилами читання (що доволі послідовні) _Microsoft_ мало би читатися ⟨місрозофт⟩, але німці пишуть у дужках транскрипцію (яка для власних німецьких слів непотрібна) і читають ⟨майкрософт⟩. Я вважаю, що у польській/чеській/словенській/хорватській так само. А Google Translate тут ні до чого — він читає слова за правилами читання самої мови, не знаючи навіть яке із запозичених Bosch мається на увазі.

Answer (score 3):

Насправді, при перекладі враховувалось звучання слова Bosch в німецькій і нідердландській мовах. Так, у випадку німецької компанії Robert Bosch GmbH дійсно [sch] завжди має звучати як [ш]. У випадку ж нідерландського художника слід враховувати особливості цієї мови. Для того щоб переконатися як це говорять самі голландські мешканці, можна послухати, наприклад, тут: [Hiëronymus Bosch](https://forvo.com/search/Hi%C3%ABronymus%20Bosch/)

Можна почути, що голландці слово Bosch в більшості промовляють як [босх]. Тому гіпотеза про те, що враховувались національні особливості вимови конкретного слова (у нашому випадку — Bosch) в певному регіоні при перекладі на українську, є найбільш вірогідною.