# Кафедра та катедра - синоніми?

Tags: синоніми

На мета є запитання [Як має виглядати наш промо-лист на **катедри** мовознавства (й до інших схожих інституцій)?](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227/%D0%AF%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%94-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%88-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D0%BE-%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%85-%D1%81%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%85-%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8)

Завжди думала, що правильно писати лише "кафедра", але в словнику знайшла "катедра".

З СУМ-20

> [Катедра](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=40942&page=1293) и, ж., зах. Те саме, що ка́федра.
>
> [Кафедра](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=41009&page=1295)
>
> 1. Поміст із похилою дошкою, укріпленою на підвищенні для лектора, викладача або промовця.
> 2. Об'єднання викладачів, науковців однієї або споріднених дисциплін у вищому навчальному закладі. / Посада завідувача такого об'єднання
>      викладачів. // Приміщення, де збираються викладачі такого об'єднання
> 3. Посада єпископа, який керує єпархією.
> 4. Те саме, що Кафедра́льний собо́р (див. собо́р).

Відміність та схожість слів пояснюється лише перекладом слів іншомовного походження? Чи можна вважати дані слова повними синонімами? Чи варто розмежовувати вживання даних слів?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хоч це запитання схоже на дублікат, але про всяк випадок надам пряму відповідь:

- **так, це повні синоніми**, згідно з визначеннями зі словника, які Ви самі навели;
- ***кафедра* наразі вживається частіше**, *катедра* вживають переважно: (1) в західних регіонах (той же словник відмічає це слово як західноукраїнське), (2) діаспора; (3) прибічники альтернативних правописів.

Див. також:

1. ["Т" чи "ф" як відповідник "Th" (Θ) при запозиченні з грецької?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/438)
2. [Як правильно: катедральний собор чи кафедральний собор?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/434)
3. [Як правильно: в прямому етері, в прямому ефірі чи наживо?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/380)